# HTML and CSS: Padding Assistance

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML and CSS, and was trying to build a webpage using whatever I've understood. I'm having problems with the "This Website" button that I'm trying to create on the top left. I want it to be centered(horizontally), for which I need about 20px worth of top padding (50px is a representative value in the code). Upon changing this value, there is no effect on the look whatsoever. How do I fix this? Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* { margin:0;padding:0;}
div.topbar {
background-color: #f44336;
height: 50px;  
}
a.left-top-bar {
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
padding-top:50px
padding-bottom: 10px;
font-family: ISOCPEUR;
text-align: center;
}
nav.sidenav {
background-color: #a4a4a4;
width: 200px;
height: 500px;
padding-top: 15px;
font-family: Calibri;
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
float: left;
text-align: center;
line-height: 45px;
}
a.nav:link, a.nav:active, a.nav:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
background-color: #949494;
padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #000000;
border-width: 2px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
a.nav:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #292929;
}

section.center {
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
}

a.topbar:link, a.topbar:visited {
background-color: #f44336;
color: white;
padding: 14px 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-family: Calibri;
}

a.topbar:hover, a.topbar:active {
background-color: red;
}
a.image:hover {
background-color: red;
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topbar">
<a class="left-top-bar">This Website</a>
</div>
<nav class="sidenav">
<a class="nav" href="https://www.wikipedia.org" target="_blank">Home</a><br> <a      class="nav" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">About Us</a>

</nav>
<section class="center">
<p>Information</p>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here first you need to study, to realize of the small mistakes you are making!!! Go GO Go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have done, but more than copy it read it and research more on how to make a website HTML , CSS

```
div.topbar {
  background-color: #f44336;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 70px;
  font-family: ISOCPEUR;
  // remove next line to see the difference...
  position: relative;  //when element is relative positioned the childs will be constrained to the parent no to the body or greather relative parent
}

a.left-top-bar {
  background-color: #0e0e0e;
  color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;  // check if you need to add relative in the parent
}
```

Good websites for reference are:

- [W3CSchools](http://w3schools.com/)
- [DWB](https://davidwalsh.name/)
- [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the position attribute earlier, but couldn't get the hang of it. I'll check it out again, and try to understand it better. :)

Comment: So basically, earlier, the padding WAS being applied, only it wasn't visible because it was above the topbar. When you applied the position:absolute attribute, it made sure that the left-top-bar was positioned relative to the topbar, right?

Comment: You go it. Padding is an space which is always inside the element box and margin goes outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/xgofzs55/

i did this fiddle for you

use

```
Position:absolute;
```